# How to Include AlloyUI

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, alloy-ui

I have some troubles including AlloyUI in my Liferay Portlet.
Following this [article](https://www.liferay.com/de/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/simple-alloyui-example-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-en), I have generated the following jsp:

```jsp
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>

<input type="text" id="some-input" />
<span id="counter"></span> character(s) remaining

<aui:script>
YUI().use(
  'aui-char-counter',
  function(Y) {
    new Y.CharCounter(
      {
        counter: '#counter',
        input: '#some-input',
        maxLength: 10
      }
    );
  }
);
</aui:script>
```

But the rendered page looks like this:

[image: field not working]

I made sure that the taglib is correctly defined in the `web.xml`:

```xml
<taglib>
    <taglib-uri>http://liferay.com/tld/aui</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/aui.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
```

AUI does work, when I include it in the jsp as follows:

```jsp
<script src="http://cdn.alloyui.com/2.0.0/aui/aui-min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.alloyui.com/2.0.0/aui/aui-min.js" rel="stylesheet"></link>


<input type="text" id="some-input" />
<span id="counter"></span> character(s) remaining

<script>
YUI().use(
  'aui-char-counter',
  function(Y) {
    new Y.CharCounter(
      {
        counter: '#counter',
        input: '#some-input',
        maxLength: 10
      }
    );
  }
);
</script>
```

[image: field working]

I'm using Liferay 6.1.20 EE GA2

Comment: You can use AUI instead YUI  and A instead Y

Comment: should I provide that as answer?

Comment: @PankajKathiriya Well you should have answered it in the first place. Were you afraid that somebody would downvote you :-). You may give some additional information also in the answer which will help others as well. I hope you read the text in the comment box when you started commenting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Liferay uses [alloy-ui](/questions/tagged/alloy-ui) (also referred to as`AUI`) library developed on top of Yahoo UI  (also referred to as [yui](/questions/tagged/yui)) library.

The instance terms for both these libraries are different i.e. `AUI` for Alloy-UI and `YUI` for the other.

Replacing these terms in your code will resolve your issue i.e. have `AUI` instead of `YUI`.

Answer (score 0):

The seed file declaration is all you need to access AlloyUI for this char counter code.

```
<script src="http://cdn.alloyui.com/2.0.0/aui/aui-min.js"></script>
```

You shouldn't need the taglib reference in your web.xml. In fact, you're inhibiting access to the seed file. The taglib you're referencing may be inconsistent with the version of AlloyUI that is expected.

Also, accessing YUI's CharCounter is fine. See the API example at http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.CharCounter.html.